# Time series questions in R

Tags: time-series

Let $X_t$ be the process satisfying the following equation:$$X_t = \phi X_{t−1} + Z_t − \theta Z_{t−2},\,\theta > 0,$$where $Z_t$ is a white noise process.

1. What conditions on $\phi$ and $\theta$ are required for this process to be stationary, causal and
   invertible? Under what conditions, the model is redundant?
2. Suppose $\phi = 0.65$ and $\theta = 0.32$. Simulate $1000$ data points from the above model and
   compute the sample [ACF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation_function) and [PACF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_autocorrelation_function).

Comment: Do you mean [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) or [$\Bbb R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number)?

Comment: R like the statisical software

Comment: So do you only need our help with question $2$?

Comment: No both i need help with both